# How do you reject an invalid JSON body using Express or Body-Parser

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm creating an application that only accepts a body type of json and uses body-parsers and express. The problem that keeps showing up is if I send an invalid json body, then my program will throw a stupid error back to the user, and in the console. How would I prevent this console error and reject a request with an improper JSON body.

Thanks in advance,
Avery.

PS. Here is some example code to show what I'm doing:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
   res.status(200).send("Hi");
});

app.listen(8081, function(){
   console.log("Server is running");
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to attach some error handling middleware to your app.  How you handle that error is up to you, but as an example of how you'd do it:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// this is a trivial implementation
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // you can error out to stderr still, or not; your choice
  console.error(err); 

  // body-parser will set this to 400 if the json is in error
  if(err.status === 400)
    return res.status(err.status).send('Dude, you messed up the JSON');

  return next(err); // if it's not a 400, let the default error handling do it. 
});

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
   res.status(200).send("Hi");
});

app.listen(8081, function(){
   console.log("Server is running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**body parser throw all kind of errors
for example**

'encoding.unsupported',
'entity.parse.failed',
'entity.verify.failed',
'request.aborted',
'request.size.invalid',
'stream.encoding.set',
'parameters.too.many',
'charset.unsupported',
'encoding.unsupported',
'entity.too.large'

if you want a more robust solution use this middleware

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-body-parser-error-handler

```
$ npm i express-body-parser-error-handler
```

**for example:**

```
const bodyParserErrorHandler = require('express-body-parser-error-handler')
const { urlencoded, json } = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    return res.json({message:""});
});

// body parser initilization
app.use('/', json({limit: '250'}));

// body parser error handler
app.use(bodyParserErrorHandler());
app.use(router);
...
```