# log incoming request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am expecting a json in my expressjs api. but i get the following error when i receive the request

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/admin/middleware-2.0/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /home/admin/middleware-2.0/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/admin/middleware-2.0/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/admin/middleware-2.0/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/admin/middleware-2.0/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Yes, I am sure that the request format is not in json, but we are not able to log to check the request. we dont have the access to the source application code to verify at the source level. how can i do it in my api.

below is express code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.post('/n2/offline', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req before', req.body)
    res.status(200).send();
} )

const port = 3001

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Message Receiver accepting requests on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: You can't log because the request is failing before the post function, before the log. You have a middleware `app.use(express.json());` that is trying to parse to json your request. Try to remove it and than check what format you're getting in the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an error handling middleware to capture the error in the console.

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  if (err.status === 400) {
    return res.status(err.status).send("Invalid JSON");
  }
  return next(err);
});
```

Source:
[How do you reject an invalid JSON body using Express or Body-Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142928/how-do-you-reject-an-invalid-json-body-using-express-or-body-parser)